# How do i get my function to find a game object with a certain distance or radius?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, distance

does anyone know what i should edit my code to find a game object within a certain distance? Currently my code can find gameobjects which is named "points" but it does not have a certain limit to which it starts to find the gameobject.
The result that i wanted is that after a line renderer had collidered with another gameobject, the one point of the line with attach/snap to one point of the ruler but the snapping needs to be activited/start when its near the "points".

Heres my current code:

```
  public Transform GetClosestpoints (Transform[] points)
  {
    bestTarget = null;
    //OppPointOfBestTarget = null;
    float closestDistanceSqr = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 currentPosition = gObjDL.mousePos;
    foreach (Transform potentialTarget in points) 
    {
        Vector3 directionToTarget = potentialTarget.position - currentPosition;
        float dSqrToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;

        if (dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr) 
        {
            if (dSqrToTarget > distance) 
            {
                closestDistanceSqr = dSqrToTarget;
                bestTarget = potentialTarget;
                Debug.Log (bestTarget);
            }
        }

    }
        return bestTarget;
}
```

Comment: You have an undefined variable `distance` in your code.

Comment: the distance is one of my public var, so its all the up way on top of my script.